# Is it possible to recover encrypted files/folders?

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-7, vmware

I've found some remnant documents on one of my hard drives that were somehow encrypted (appearing green in Windows 7 Ultimate x64).

I've attempted to uncheck Encryption in their properties, but I get access denied. I've figured this to be because the files were from a previous format/iteration of my desktop setup, and must have somehow inadvertently gotten encrypted. (I now believe it had something to do with transferring them at one point onto a Mac machine/drive, and then back, not realizing that they were encrypted until post-format).

I originally posted in this question that I thought I had a VMware image from the same time period as the files, and that perhaps it'd be possible to transfer the key from that image to my current machine, but that image is not the right one! :/ I don't have an image that goes back further.

I've tried copying the files to a FAT32 USB drive (as it would strip the encryption), but Windows 7 denies that (understandably). And as expected, trying to drag/copy the files from my current machine onto the VMware running machine also gets denied, as VMware is running within Win7's domain and rules.

Any ideas? What about booting my current machine off of a linux live USB stick, and then attempting to copy the NTFS encrypted files onto a FAT32 partition (thus removing the encryption) -- Would that work, seeing as how Windows wouldn't be "awake" to prohibit copying?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a zip archive where these files originated from. Whenever I extracted them, however, they'd appear green. Sure enough, there's also a MACOSX folder in the zip file (no idea why Windows decides to encrypt anything that's coming from a Mac).

I was able to copy the zip file onto the old VMware image of mine and extract the zip file there. It still came up as encrypted, but right clicking the folder, clicking properties, and unchecking Encryption fully decrypted the folder and files!

I'd assume that even though this VMware image's machine name was different from the user record within the file's encryption information, it likely was actually the same, originating machine and subsequent encryption certificates.

Anyway, I was able to copy the decrypted files back, and now the problem's solved!